# how to pass variable from server js file to another

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, api, express

i am building an easy weather web page. i get the weather info from the open weather api using a node js server file

the thing is, once i get the weather info like temperature and then set it on a variable i cant pass it to my other javascript file so as to be able to display it on my new html file. i want to pass the weatherState variable to another js file so as to have it in my weather.html. this is the code

```
app.post("/", function(req, res) {
    const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london&appid=****&units=metric

  https.get(url, function(response) {
    response.on("data", function(data) {
      const weatherData = JSON.parse(data);
      var weatherState = "The temperature in london  is: " + weatherData.main.temp + " degrees
      res.sendFile(__dirname + "/weather.html");

    });
  });
});
```

I ve tried doing the module.export thing but browsers wont let me require from other files using node.

i simply want to have the weatherState variable displayed on my weather.html file some way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Ejs Template with node js. Find the link here
https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application